# Invertible matrix and linear independence

Tags: matrices

Actually this is a question in general linear model in statistics, but I'm struggling with properties of invertible matrix involved. The questions are as follows:

If X is a n*p matrix, with the first column all 1, and in each row, the last p-1 columns sum to a certain value, then 
1. are the columns linearly dependent? 
2. is (X^T X) invertible?

If X is a n*p matrix, with the sum of the last p-1 columns equal to the first column, then 
1. are the columns linearly dependent? 
2. is (X^T X) invertible? 
3. is it correct that there are only p-1 linear combinations among the columns?

This question maybe a bit stupid, but any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: What is a n*p matrix?  Do you mean $n\; $x$\; p$?

Comment: yes, sorry I didn't use the formula writing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the columns of $X$ are linearly independent if and only if $X^\top X$ is an invertible $p\times p$ matrix.

In the case of your second question, we can say for sure that the columns are linearly dependent (because the sum of the last columns plus the negative of the first column add to the zero vector). However, in the case of your first question, if I understand it correctly, it could go either way. Please specify exactly what you mean by saying that the last columns "sum to a certain value."

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I understand now, for example, in the first situation of a n*p matrix, if the last p-1 columns sum to 100, and the first columns are all 1, then can I say because the sum of last p columns minus 100 times the first column equal to 0, so they are linearly dependent?

Comment: Oh, are you saying that the *rows* of the last columns add up to $100$? This is why I was confused. Yes, if that's what you mean, then you definitely have linear dependence of the columns.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused now, I mean each row of the columns, and also for the second question, then does the result that columns being linearly independent still hold for the second question? does rows also have to be linearly independent for X^T X to be invertible?

Comment: LOL, I didn't mean to confuse you. It's just that to say that "columns sum to a certain value" is very ambiguous. ... And, no, for rows to be independent, we need $XX^\top$ to be invertible.